In Android 11, when the device is turned off and then back on, the services do not start
In Kotlin, when we completely off the device and then turn on, the services are not starting in Android 11
<receiver>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category."/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

and we are used this permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

in versions prior to Android 11, this functionality works properly. Any way to solve this problem?

In Android 11 they changed a lot about Privacy and Security including changes to Background location access and Foreground services. See the top privacy changes in the changelist. This might help you identify your issue as it is extremely hard up to impossible to answer your question without knowing your codebase.
In general it is important to read the changelist of newer Android versions and check if there might be colissions for your codebase.

Thanks for your answer, Service is workingas expected on Android 12 and 13 only issue with 11. Any other suggestion?

@SaurabhYadav without knowing your codebase and being able to debug anything it is nearly impossible to give you more insights. Me (and I think other people) cannot contribute more into your question.
